# What does it mean for a network interface to be primary?

Tags: wireless, networking, ethernet

If I have two network interfaces, like eth0 and wlan0, what does it mean if I configure wlan0 to be primary? Is eth0 disabled and unused until I configure it to be primary? Does it mean the primary interface is the one being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much. I guess if you lose signal at wlan0, then it will switch to eth0, but it should use wlan0 as soon as it's up.